# b1/b2 visa - change of circumstances

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

I'm a citizen of Ukraine and therefore I need a visa to enter the US. 3 years ago I was going on a business trip to NY and so I got my b1/b2 visa which is valid for 10 years. Since then I've got a new job and moved to a different country - I have a work permit visa in the UK.  Here I met my girlfriend who has a dual US/UK citizenship.  We are going on a trip to the US for one week and will be staying at her parents'.

At first I was confident I can use my visa with no problem as it is still valid. But not I'm getting a bit worried about this trip - so many things have changed since I applied for visa 3 years ago. Is this going to be a problem? Is there anything I really should be worried about? Do I need to bring any documents with me to prove my purpose of visit? I only have my passport and return tickets.

Thanks!

Comment: It’s fine. They can’t expect your life to stay still for 10 days. As long as your activities are within the permitted ones you don’t have to have exactly the same scenario as when you initially applied

Comment: Your wife being a USA citizen could be a problem.

Comment: @Fattie I think he meant 10 years. That's how long my visa i valid for. My trip will be 8 days long.

Comment: @greatone she's not even my wife, she's my gf. Or should i  not mention this when asked?

Comment: Don't worry about @greatone's comment.  You're well settled in the UK; they're not going to suspect you of trying to immigrate to the US unless something unusual comes up, especially since your girlfriend also lives in the UK.  I (US citizen) visited the US several times from Europe with a non-US girlfriend and there was never any problem at the immigration desk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purely one man's opinion, I am *fairly certainly* this will be no problem whatsoever.

Note that, even, when you arrive at JFK or the like, and you are waiting to go through immigration, you will likely be in different lines.  (She "citizen" line, you "scary foreigner we don't trust" line.)

It's very likely it won't even come up that you are traveling with her.

(If you are specifically asked for some reason, of course explain it.  Just say "My girlfriend over there, she's from the UK, we're both visiting her parents who live in Peeboken...". That's it!)

Comment: It is not necessary for them to go to different lines.  They can go together to the US citizens line.  In fact, if they live together, they *should* do so because they should submit a single customs declaration.  Even when I entered the US with a girlfriend who lived in an entirely different country, the immigration officer threw out her customs declaration and added her to mine.  He also confirmed that we should use the US citizens' line together.